# Derivative of a Solution Function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Consider an ordinary linear second order differential equation in the following form:

$$
a_2y''(t) + a_1y'(t) +a_0y(t) = u(t)
$$

where $u(t) = \begin{cases} 0&t\leq 0 \\ 1 &t>0 \end{cases}$, and $a_i\text{'s}\in [0,1]$. (The second constraint doesn't really matter, and I can safely assume $a_i\text{'s}\in \mathbb{R}$)

I only care about the particular solution of the ODE.

Obviously, the solution of this ODE will be a function of  $t$, $a_2$, $a_1$ and $a_0$.

My question is: Are there easy ways to evaluate the derivative of the solution with respect to each of the $a_i$'s when the other two coefficients are constants?

For example, let $a_1=a_0=.3$, what is $\frac{\partial y(t)}{\partial a_2}\rvert_{a_2=.5}$? (Of course, this is just an example.)

We can assume that I have the closed-form solution for $y(t)$, and for its first and second derivatives with respect to $t$: $y'(t)$ and $y''(t)$ for fixed $a_i$'s.

For example:

Let's assume my ODE is : $.5*y''(t) + .1*y'(t) + .5*y(t) =u(t)$
Then the solution will be:

$y(t) = 2. u(t) +(-2 cos(0.994987 t) -         0.201008 * sin(0.994987 t))u(t) + e^{-t} (c_2 cos(0.994987 t) + c_1 Sin(0.994987 t) $

(Solved by Mathematica)

Now, by the particular solution, I mean: $y_p(t) = 2. u(t) +(-2 cos(0.994987 t) -         0.201008 * sin(0.994987 t)) u(t)$

Comment: fixed value has not derivate!

Comment: I might need to adjust the language, but, I mean evaluation of the derivative at a point, where two of the coefficients are fixed, but the solution is a function of $t$ and the other, not-fixed coefficient as a variable.

Comment: @MyGlasses: I adjusted the language, thanks for your comment. Please let me know if the question is still vague.

Comment: OK. Any boundary or initial conditions?

Comment: I only care about the particular solution; in specific, I set  $c1$ and $c_2$, (the coefficients of the homogeneous solutions) to zero.

Comment: What do you mean by "**the** particular solution"?  As with any second-order linear ODE, the solutions form a two-dimensional affine space.  You can single out any member of that space as a "particular solution", and the general solution is that plus a solution of the homogeneous equation.

Comment: @robertIsrael: I mean the solution at the origin of this two-dimensional affine space of functions.

Comment: An affine space does not have a distinguished origin.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Thank you! I guess I need to rewrite my question. In my original formulation $u(t)$ was the sigmoid function ($u(x)=1/(1+e^{-t})$), but since evaluation of the Hyp2F1 (Gauss Hypergeometric) function was expensive. I switched to this approximation. But now, it is harder to draw a discriminative line between the general and particular solutions. I need to decide on the initial conditions as you guys suggested. But, that doesn't change the nature of the questions; what if I have $y(0) = y_0$ and $y'(0)=y'_0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suppose the "particular" solution you're interested in is the one that satisfies the initial conditions $y(0)=0$, $y'(0) = 0$.  If $y_0(t)$ is the solution of the homogeneous equation with initial conditions
$$ y_0(0)=1,\; y'_0(0) = 0$$ this will be of the form

$$ y_p(t) = a_0^{-1} (1 - y_0(t)) u(t) $$

Now $$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial a_2} y_p(t) = - a_0^{-1} u(t) \dfrac{\partial}{\partial a_2} y_0(t) $$

Now by differentiating the homogeneous differential equation and initial conditions with respect to $a_2$, we see that $v(t) = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial a_2} y_0(t)$ is the solution of the differential equation

$$  a_2 v''(t) + a_1 v'(t) + a_0 v(t) = - y_0''(t)$$

with

$$ v(0) = 0,\; v'(0) = 0 $$